# выборка в mysql: массив - массив

Tags: mysql

**Есть массив** вида array(1, 10, 22) - то, что выбрал в форме пользователь (в данном случае выбрано 3 категории). 
**Есть БД**, где для каждой записи указаны определенные категории, которым она соответствует (может быть от 1 до 50 в разном сочетании, к примеру 13, 22). 
**Вопрос**: как мне отобрать те записи в БД, которые были отмечены пользователем.

Comment: указаны они как? как строка через запятую? Структура базы не ясна

Comment: да,  через запятую

Comment: Нормализуйте структуру. На текущей - запрос получится слишком бредовым.